# Is there a way to catch poorly covered queries in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I've enabled the notablescan parameter to block non-indexed db queries from running:

```
db.getSiblingDB("admin").runCommand( { setParameter: 1, notablescan: 1 })
```

Which works great for queries that aren't covered at all but i'm looking for a way to achieve the same behavior for queries that are inadequately covered.

#### Sample document that lives in the user collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53ea97c07567085b548b49c0"),
    "site_id": 1,
    "created_date" : ISODate("2014-08-12T22:40:00.746Z")
}
```

#### Sample Collection Indexes for the user collection

```
db.users.ensureIndex({'created_date':1})
```

#### Sample Query

```
db.users.find({'user_id': 1}).sort({'created_date': -1})
```

#### Expected Result

```
error: {
    "$err" : "Unable to execute query: error processing query: ns=collect.user limit=0 skip=0\nTree: site_id == 1.0\nSort: {}\nProj: {}\n No query solutions",
    "code" : 17007
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I currently do is enable [profiling](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.setProfilingLevel/)

```
$ mongo your_db
> db.setProfilingLevel(2)
```

This profiles all queries, and stores a record of how long it took to execute.

Then prepare a nightly cron job that gives you the 10 slowest queries of that day:

```
#!/bin/bash
now=$(date --iso-8601=date --utc -d "-1 day")
results=$(mongo your_db --eval "db.system.profile.find( { ts: {\$gte: ISODate('$now')} } ).sort({millis: -1}).limit(10).forEach(function(e){printjson(e);})"
)
host=$(hostname)
mail -s "Mongo Slow Queries for $now@$host" your.email@gmail.com << HERE
$results
HERE
```

So in the end, you are simply reactive to any performance issues that occur (and add the appropriate index). Not all collections require an index.

Of course you can change the script to output to a file instead of email, and also set it to run on an hourly or weekly basis depending on your needs.

Comment: Of course this should come with the usual common sense note of: beware of doing this in production. There are better tools actually like MMS. Also note the profile collection is not infinite, it is capped collection and it's size depends on queries against it.

Answer (score 0):

I checked with Mongo Support and they've mentioned a future 3.2 release that may include the ability to add an index counter tool, but for now the profiler is the best bet. Thanks @Martin!